# Understanding the effect OrbitControls has on the orientation of camera in threejs

Tags: javascript, three.js, orbitcontrols

I have an application which makes use of Obritcontrols to allow the user to manipulate camera position and orientation in a scene with their mouse. I notice that simply using OrbitControls has some surprising effects on the worldmatrix of the camera for the scene and was wondering if anyone can explain what is going on.

For instance, the following code

```
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera (45, width/height, 1, 10000);
console.log("camera.matrixWorld = ");
console.log(JSON.stringify(camera.matrixWorld));
camera.position.y = 160;
camera.position.z = 400;
camera.lookAt (new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0));
console.log("camera.matrixWorld = ");
console.log(JSON.stringify(camera.matrixWorld));
controls = new OrbitControls (camera, renderer.domElement);
console.log("camera.matrixWorld = ");
console.log(JSON.stringify(camera.matrixWorld));
```

produces the output
camera.matrixWorld =  {"elements":[1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1]}
camera.matrixWorld =  {"elements":[1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,160,400,1]} camera.matrixWorld = {"elements":[1,0,0,0,0,0.9284766908852593,-0.3713906763541037,0,0,0.3713906763541037,0.9284766908852593,0,0,160.00000000000003,400,1]}

so it appears that orbitcontrols modifies the worldmatrix of the camera even although no commands to alter the matrix have been issued and the user has not had a chance to move the camera. I was wondering how to understand this?

Comment: *no commands to alter the matrix have been issued* - what makes you thing that no commands have been issued? Did you look at the source code? https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js